# Adding a column of totals using dplyr in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

how would you add a column to this dataset showing the number of individuals of each species?.

```
install.packages("ggplot")
library(ggplot)
library(ggplot2)
```

```
starwars
```

[image]

So far this is what I have tried:

```
num <- starwars %>% group_by(species)
num
```

Comment: what code have you tried? please share

Comment: num <- starwars %>% group_by(species)
num

Comment: try looking at `?count()` its a short cut for the more general`group_by(...) %>% summarise(...)`

Answer (score 0):

In the case where all you need is the count of the number of individuals/records within a group you can use `dplyr::count()`. Note that `sort=TRUE` will sort counts in *decreasing* order, contrary to the default behavior of sort functions in base R.

```
starwars %>% 
  count(species, sort = TRUE)
```

This is shorthand for something like what is below where you summarize the number of rows in each group. After counting the rows in each group I `arrange()` them in decreasing (`desc()`) order of `n`.

```
library(dplyr)
starwars %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))
```

More generally in the place of `count()` you can use `summarize()` and `n()` if for instance you need to do some other calculation with the counts or summarize some other data elements.

Here  with `summarize()` I divide the count by the number of rows in the original dataset to make a proportion a column named `foo`

```
library(dplyr)
starwars %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarize(foo = n() / nrow(starwars)) %>%
  arrange(desc(foo))
```

Comment: Your first chunk is completely equivalent to `starwars %>% count(species, sort = TRUE)`. If two codes do the same thing, we prefer the concise one.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I modified my post .

Answer (score 0):

Use `add_count`

```
library(dplyr)

starwars %>% 
  add_count(species, name = "Total_species")
```

`add_count`: does the same as: (note **mutate**)

```
starwars %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  mutate(n = n())
```

in contrast:

`count`: does the following: (note **summarise**)

```
starwars %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())
```

```
   name     height  mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year sex   gender homeworld species films vehicles starships Total_species
   <chr>     <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>   <lis> <list>   <list>            <int>
 1 Luke Sk~    172    77 blond      fair       blue            19   male  mascu~ Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [2]>            35
 2 C-3PO       167    75 NA         gold       yellow         112   none  mascu~ Tatooine  Droid   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>             6
 3 R2-D2        96    32 NA         white, bl~ red             33   none  mascu~ Naboo     Droid   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>             6
 4 Darth V~    202   136 none       white      yellow          41.9 male  mascu~ Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [1]>            35
 5 Leia Or~    150    49 brown      light      brown           19   fema~ femin~ Alderaan  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>            35
 6 Owen La~    178   120 brown, gr~ light      blue            52   male  mascu~ Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>            35
 7 Beru Wh~    165    75 brown      light      blue            47   fema~ femin~ Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>            35
 8 R5-D4        97    32 NA         white, red red             NA   none  mascu~ Tatooine  Droid   <chr> <chr>    <chr [0]>             6
 9 Biggs D~    183    84 black      light      brown           24   male  mascu~ Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [1]>            35
10 Obi-Wan~    182    77 auburn, w~ fair       blue-gray       57   male  mascu~ Stewjon   Human   <chr> <chr>    <chr [5]>            35
```

Answer (score -1):

Loading in the dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
head(starwars)
```

What we want to do is to clean up some of the NAs in general. This is optional, but I am doing it in this case. We will also create a tibble containing the counts of each species.

```
starwars_clean <- starwars %>% na.omit()
species_counts <- starwars_clean %>%
  count(species) %>%
  mutate(species_count = n)
```

Afterwards, we want to merge the two tibbles (something like a left join in a relational database) based on the `species` column. A left join is denoted by the `all.x = TRUE` argument.

```
joined_tibble <- merge(
  x = starwars_clean,
  y = species_counts,
  by = "species",
  all.x = TRUE
)

head(joined_tibble)
```

We will have the `species_count` column for each row of the  `starwars` tibble.

Comment: All you did was just `starwars %>% add_count(species, name = "species_count")`. If two codes do the same thing, we prefer the concise one. In addition, don't arbitrarily discard those rows with `NA`. In this case, the original data has 87 observations. After doing `na.omit()`, 29 rows remain. Over 50% information is discarded. I cannot find any reasons to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Will revise my answers when I get back to my computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).